# Homomorphism from a product of spin groups to a bigger spin group

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, spin-geometry

In the paper "Essential dimension of spinor and clifford groups" by Chernousov and Merkurjev, it says that there is a natural homomorphism

$\operatorname{Spin}(n)\times \operatorname{Spin}(m)\to \operatorname{Spin}(n+m)$.

Of course, we know that there is a natural homomorphism
$\operatorname{SO}(n)\times \operatorname{SO}(m)\to \operatorname{SO}(n+m)$ but it doesn't directly tell us that there also exists spin version. What is the homomorphism written above?

Comment: Given a connected Lie group $G$ and choice of subgroup $A \subset \pi_1 G$, one may naturally associate the cover $p_A: \tilde G_A \to G$ so that $p_A(\pi_1 \tilde G_A) = A$. This covering space has a unique group structure so that the map $p_A$ is a group homomorphism (this uses that $G$ is connected). If I have a map $f: G \to G'$ with $f(A) \subset A'$, then there is a unique group homomorphism $\tilde f: \tilde G_A \to \tilde G'_{A'}$ which fits into the appropriate commutative diagram. The map $\tilde f$ is uniquely determined by the property that it covers $f$ and has $\tilde f(e) = e$.

Comment: I should say: once you choose the basepoint $\tilde e$ with $p_A(\tilde e) = e$, this covering space has a unique group structure ...

Comment: The easy way to see this is to observe that ${\rm SO}_n\times{\rm SO} _m$ is (the connected component of) the fixed point subgroup in ${\rm SO}_{n+m}$ for an involution - inner if and only if at least one of $n, m$ is even - and this involution lifts to an involution of ${\rm Spin}_{n+m}$ (by universality/mme's argument). The connected component of the fixed point subgroup for this involution is the subgroup you want.

Comment: @mme Oh I forgot about the lifting criterion... Thanks for reminding me of it.

Comment: @PaulLevy Thanks for your comment